# How to dynamically set max-width of sibling in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Is it possible to set max-width of a div to same value as width of its sibling (in angular6)?

In other words, can I set max-width of "child_two" to the same value as width of "child_one" with the constraint that I just know the width of "child_one" when it is rendered?

```
`<div class="parent-div">
   <div id="child_one" class="child-div"> </div>
   <div id="child_two" class="child-div"> </div>
 </div>`
```

Comment: Can you use `flex` CSS rules?

Comment: would be better without flexbox. Unless it is the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind the `max-width` style attribute of `child_two` to the `offsetWidth` of `child_one`, with the help of a template reference variable `child1`:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div id="child_one" class="child-div" #child1 > </div>
  <div id="child_two" class="child-div" [style.max-width.px]="child1.offsetWidth"> </div>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnhkrh) for a demo.